# On python, how do I get rid of quotations after joining a list of floats?

Tags: python, list, csv, join

Apologies if this has been asked before, I couldn't find the same question.

I'm trying to write 3 things to a CSV file in one line, `productcode`, `amountentered` and `changecoins`. 
The changecoins is a list of floats which I have joined together using `changecoins=",".join(map(str,changecoins))`. This works fine except I still have quotations around the values which are then written into my csv file.

I've tried using strip and replace but they don't seem to work. 
I've attached my code and output in the csv file below, does anyone know how to fix this?

```
changecoins=",".join(map(str,changecoins)).replace('"', '')
changeline=(productcode, amountentered, changecoins)
changewriter.writerow(changeline)
```

**Output**

```
01,1.0,"0.1,0.1"
01,2.0,"0.5,0.5,0.1,0.1"
04,1.0,"0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1"
```

Comment: Can you post your code in the question? So we can help.

Comment: Is that enough of the code to help?

Comment: @dstudeba Delete the image when editing the question! It is bad to put the code in an image, better write it in the question.

Comment: Why not just leave the list of floats as is?

Comment: @lbellomo You can delete it if you want, I didn't want to type the whole thing in for her.

Comment: have you tried out my solution? it should work.

Comment: question, is productcode and amountentered a string or a float?

Comment: I left it alone originally but it stayed as a list in the csv file with [] around it

Comment: productcode is an integer, amountentered is a float

Comment: yeah, try out my solution below. let me know what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use extend?

```
result = [productcode, amountentered]
result.extend(changecoins)
changewriter.writerow(result)
```

if you want to get even more slick, you can just do:

```
result = [productcode, amountentered] + changecoins
changewriter.writerow(result)
```

or even just:

```
changewriter.writerow([productcode, amountentered] + changecoins)
```

It seems you're unnecessarily joining the floats...You already have a list of floats, just tack it on to the other two guys and then pass that to your csv writer.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Totally misread OP. It doesn't have to be a tuple though.

Comment: This worked, thankyou! This has been annoying me for a while.

Comment: if this worked for you, please consider accepting my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely because you're using "," to join your values when the CSV delimiter is also a ,. Python is wrapping the column in quotes so the "," inside the cell value isn't confused for a delimiter.

If you change to joining with a different character than "," or change the delimiter for the file, the quotes will go away.

Comment: The file was given to us as part of an assignment so I can't edit it and it needs to have commas in the final output, is there a way of getting round this?

Comment: You can modify your csv writer to use a different delimeter for the columns, the problem is that if you somehow managed to get rid of the quotes around the column value, any application you open that CSV with after the fact would either error out or treat them as individual column values versus a single value as it would split the line into columns on the "," delimeter.

Comment: You can specify a different delimiter when you instantiate your changewriter for instance you could use ";" or "|" as the delimiter for the output columns in the csv `csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)` then the csv module wouldn't force quotes around your column value in order to protect the inner ","

Comment: I take it I can't get the output to be 01,1.0,0.1,0.1? I've changed the delimiter which changes the output to 01;1.0;0.1,0.1

Comment: I think you have to clarify what you're looking for, are you looking for changecoins to be treated as a single column, or are you looking to output a csv with variable number of columns for each row based on the number of changecoins list items, if it's the latter then what you need is @deweyredman answer.